# Read variables used in useMutation

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have an Apollo GraphQL mutation. This mutation accepts two variables.
I would like to read these variables once the mutation is fired (not as response from the backed).
I need to know these variables because I want to use them inside the `onCompleted` function.

My code:

```
  const [tripleEntity] = useMutation(TRIPLE_ENTITY, {
    context: { clientName: 'redzor' },
    refetchQueries: ['listProjects']
  })
```

What I would like:

```
  const [tripleEntity] = useMutation(TRIPLE_ENTITY, {
    context: { clientName: 'redzor' },
    refetchQueries: ['listsEntities'],
    onCompleted(response, variables): {
       console.log(variables) // Where "variables" are the input necessary to fire this mutation
       myFunction(variables) // This is the function that needs the input variables
    }   
  })
```

Comment: save variables in state, call mutation in effect?

Comment: Thanks, that can be a solution. I would like still to know if it is possible to access those variables after the mutation has been called.

Answer (score 1):

`onComplete` is only passed the mutation result as a parameter -- nothing else. However, `mutate` returns a Promise, so using `onCompleted` is not necessary.

```
const [mutate] = useMutation(YOUR_MUTATION, {...})
const doSomething = async (options) => {
  const result = await mutate(options)
  yourFunction(options.variables)
}
```